# Highcharts numericSymbols when rendered server-side with Phantomjs

Tags: json, highcharts, phantomjs

Is there a way to change the numericSymbols when rendering a Highchart on a server with Phantomjs?
I generate the JSON locally on the server and pass it to Phantomjs as a parameter along with the highcharts-convert.js script and my output file

My graphs are rendered to images fine but I need to in effect do the same server-side (or via JSON) that is done on a browser client by setting the global options with:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang:{
        numericSymbols: null
    }
});
```

Is there a way of doing it with the callback maybe?
Or is there a JSON object that this can be done with?

Comment: What type of `numericSymbols` are bothering you ! Can please post an image of it ?

Comment: Instead of setting lang, you can use formatter in the labels / tooltip options and format correct form by highcharts.numberFormat;

Comment: The numeric symbols I'm referring to are the "k", "M" type symbols that replace the "000" in e.g. 1000 or 10000 making them 1k or 10k, or the "000,000" in e.g. 1000000 or 10000000 making them 1M or 10M.

Comment: I can't use a formatter either because you can't include a javascript function when the whole plot is defined in a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/setting-global-options-on-export-server-t28909/

It helped me to solve my `decimalPoint` problem.
If you are using the POST method, just follow the instructions in the link, if using the command line method (like me), just add `globaloptions` as a parameter:

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile temp/test.js -outfile temp/chart.png -globaloptions temp/test2.js
```

And the content of temp/test2.js was in my case:

```
{
    lang:{
        decimalPoint:",",
        thousandsSep:"."
    }
};
```